# Function attaining its minimum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and let there be positive constants $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)\geq (ax-\sqrt{b})(ax+\sqrt{b})$. Show that $f$ attains its minimum in $\mathbb{R}$.

I would write what I've tried so far, but I don't really have any idea how to approach this problem other than multiplying the RHS of the inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x \in \mathbb R$, you have $g(x) = (ax-\sqrt{b})(ax+\sqrt{b}) = a^2x^2-b \ge -b$. Therefore:

1. $f$ is such that $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm \infty} = \infty$.
2. Is bounded below by $-b$.

Based on that, you can prove that $f$ attains its minimum as it is supposed to be continuous.

For the proof, according to element 1., it exists $M>0$ such that for $\vert x \vert > M$ we have $ \vert f(x) \vert \ge 2 \vert f(0) \vert$. Then on the compact segment $[-M,M]$, the continuous map $f$ attains its extreme values. In particular its minimum. But this minimum is also the minimum of $f$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about applying the extreme value theorem, however, I don't really see how I can use the fact that $f$ is bounded below by $-b$.

Comment: Do you know that any continuous map attains its sup and inf on a compact interval?

Comment: Yes I do, that's what the the extreme value theorem says.

Comment: I added some details in the answer. In fact point 1. of the answer alone is enough for the proof.

Answer (score 0):

By the inequality proposed, the limit of f in both infinities is +infinity.
Try to use the definition of the limit to minimise the search of the minimum to a line segment of R.
Edit: The proof I am proposing requires the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. I suggest you check it out.

Comment: Thank you, but then I would have to construct a sequence $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f(x_n)$ approaches the minimum. However, I haven't been able to do this so far since I don't know where the minimum lies or if it even exists. Could you maybe help me with that?

Comment: Try using the definition of the lower bound by epsilon, subsititute epsilon for 1/n and construct a sequence f(xn), use Bolzano Weierstrass to construct a convergent sequence out of the sequence that you just made (here lies the importance of minimising the search into a line segment, the limit lies in the line segment), and conclude using the continuity of f.